# Conexão USB com Microcontrolador no Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microcontrolador, usb

Tenho um microcontrolador programado para enviar dados no *Visual Studio c#* através da classe `USB Hid Net Class`. Tenho a licença para a utilização da classe já e a aplicação rodou normalmente em vários computadores. Os dados são passados através do cabo USB.

No entanto ao conectar o cabo USB em um computador específico ele não recebe os dados, aparenta nem conectar o cabo USB. Será que pode ser alguma configuração do próprio computador que recebe os dados?

Segue abaixo o código de conexão com o `PIC18F4550`.

```
  private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        easyUSBHidNetClass.DeviceUSB_Config_VID_PID(0x4601, 0x9725); //VID and PID PLACA 1
        easyUSBHidNetClass1.DeviceUSB_Config_VID_PID(0x2920, 0x2112); //VID and PID PLACA 2
    }
```

Obs: A versão do Windows é Windows 8.

Comment: Verificou se a porta usb está de funcionando de fato nessa máquina?

Comment: Sim, com pen drive funciona normalmente...

Comment: Se funciona em outros computadores, o problema está no computador e não no código. Verificou se tem outros periféricos USB neste computador? Se sim desconecte-os. Também é bom verificar se as portas USB estão entregando energia suficiente